# SQL - Select Record High For Each Day of the Week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

It returns all rows sorted by CountOfRecords DESC. I'd like to have just seven rows here, showing the highest value ever for the specified day. So each day of the week should occur once and only once. Is this possible without a lot of pain?

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) As CountOfRecords, 
    CAST(FLOOR(CAST([visit].[datetimeentered] AS float)) AS smalldatetime) AS DateEntered, 
    DatePart(dw, visit.datetimeentered) As DayOfTheWeek
FROM visit
INNER JOIN useragent ON useragent.useragentid = visit.useragentid
WHERE useragent.isbot = 0
GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST([visit].[datetimeentered] AS float)) AS smalldatetime), 
    DatePart(dw, visit.datetimeentered)
ORDER BY CountOfRecords DESC
```

**Edit1:**
I think both answers are getting at the same thing. I've accepted the one that was posted first. I'm also going to mention that it worked right off the bat while the other did not. I'm getting the following errors when I run marc_s's query:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Invalid column name 'RowNum'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'CountOfRecords'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'DateEntered'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'DayOfTheWeek'.
```

Special thanks to marc_s for pointing out a simple way to get the only the date portion from a datetime.

Comment: You're already grouping the data in what appears to be the correct way for your problem - is there a reason you cannot add MAX(fieldname) where fieldname is the field for which you want the highest available value - to your SELECT ?

Comment: What database product and version? It smells like SQL Server. If so, what version?

Comment: I failed to mention that this is SQL Server 2008. I tried your suggestion and it did not work.

Comment: I think it must be allowed to accept a different answer instead the one you accepted earlier.

Comment: Oops, maybe I selected the wrong one as the answer. I thought Andriy's was showing as being posted 2 minutes ahead of marc_s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query:

```
WITH groupedByDay AS (
  SELECT 
    Count(*) As CountOfRecords, 
    CAST(FLOOR(CAST([visit].[datetimeentered] AS float)) AS smalldatetime) AS DateEntered
  FROM visit
  INNER JOIN useragent ON useragent.useragentid = visit.useragentid
  WHERE useragent.isbot = 0
  GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST([visit].[datetimeentered] AS float)) AS smalldatetime)
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    CountOfRecords,
    DateEntered,
    DOW = DATENAME(dw, DateEntered),
    rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DatePart(dw, DateEntered)
                              ORDER BY CountOfRecords DESC)
  FROM groupedByDay
)
SELECT
  CountOfRecords,
  DateEntered,
  DOW
FROM ranked
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY CountOfRecords DESC
```

This will return one row for each day of week represented in the table. If there may be duplicates by `CountOfRecords` among the maximum values and you want to return them all, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2005 and newer, you could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function and a `PARTITION BY` clause - something like this:

```
;WITH DataByDayOfWeek AS
(
   SELECT 
      Count(*) As CountOfRecords,
      CAST(FLOOR(CAST(v.[datetimeentered] AS float)) AS smalldatetime) AS DateEntered, 
      DatePart(dw, v.datetimeentered) As DayOfTheWeek
   FROM dbo.visit v
   INNER JOIN dbo.useragent u ON u.useragentid = v.useragentid
   WHERE u.isbot = 0
   GROUP BY 
       CAST(FLOOR(CAST(v.[datetimeentered] AS float)) AS smalldatetime), 
       DatePart(dw, v.datetimeentered)
),
HighestValues AS
(
    SELECT 
       CountOfRecords,
       DateEntered,
       DayOfTheWeek,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DayOfTheWeek 
                         ORDER BY CountOfRecords DESC) 'RowNum'
    FROM DataByDayOfWeek
)
SELECT 
   CountOfRecords,
   DateEntered,
   DayOfTheWeek
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Let me explain:

- the first CTE does the counting of the records, basically - so you'll get one entry for each `DateEntered` with the record count and the day of week
- the second CTE is based on that first CTE, and it "partitions" your data by `DayOfTheWeek` - so for each distinct day of the week, you get a counter starting at 1. The data for each day of the week is sorted by record count in a descending fashion, so the highest value has `RowNum` which is 1

So selecting all the rows from the second CTE which have `RowNum = 1` gives you the highest value for each day of the week.

As a side note: I believe in SQL Server 2008, you could much more easily convert your datetime to a strict `DATE` which only has the `DATE` - no time - like this:

```
CAST(v.DateTimeEntered AS DATE)
```

No more hassle with convert to a float and then to a `smalldatetime` - try it!